# User dynamically enters 2 dates and gets days as difference

Tags: php, date, date-difference

What I am trying to achieve is basically the user will enter 2 dates and get back the difference in days. I have seen other related questions in SO but none answer my question.

Following is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
$startdate = $_POST['startdate']; // starting date
$enddate = $_POST['enddate']; // end date
$now = strtotime($startdate);
$your_date = strtotime($enddate);
$datediff = $your_date - $now;
$number = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
?>

</head>
<body>
<form name="date_form" action="" method="POST"">
<input type="text" name="startdate" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="enddate" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="submit_start" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help in pointing what all changes I should make. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$number` already contains number of days. What else do you want?

Comment: but i want the output as a number (Example 14 , if the difference between both dates is 14 days )

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) for date math. *Much* easier to do.

---

but if you want to use `date()` :

`date()` function get 2nd parameter  as time stamp and returns the date : `1970-1-1 00:00:00 GMT` **+** `given time stamp` , pay attention to **GMT** part. 
it means if your time zone is **+2**, then `echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",0)` returns `1970-1-1 2:00:00` , **not** `1970-1-1 00:00:00`.

So, the result that you are getting, is (real different) **+** `2 hours`(your time zone) . if you insist of getting the result using `date()`, you must change the last lines to:

```
$number = floor( ( $datediff-$YOUR_TIME_ZONE ) /(60*60*24));
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Why you making the for loop?

```
$number = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

`$number` is the diffrence in days.

Comment: i tried echo count ($number) , but didn't get me what i wanted

Comment: You dont need to count. $number is containing the days diffrence.

Comment: i noticed that while writing , hugely embarrassed i am . Was a silly mistake .